# tastypie: PUT does not work: error cannot access body after reading from request's data stream

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm trying django-tastypie with a REST client in my browser (Postman)

GET works well:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/entry/
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/entry/1/
```

But I can't get PUT works with an entry:

```
PUT GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/entry/1/
```

I get this error:

```
{
    "error_message": "You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream",
    ...
}
```

I allowed the method in the resource though.
Where can it come from?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I have found a solution.

On postman, choose the 'raw' option and type the json data.
Then add a Content-Type header by clicking on the 'Headers' button on the top right. Type "application/json".